# How can I iterate through a dictionary that contains a dictionary that contains another dictionary which contains a list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I wanna change the value of the objects that are in a list. The List itself is in a dictionary, which is in a dictionary, which is in a dictionary. Do I have to iterate through each of them separately? I tried it with multiple foreachs, however I wasnt successful.

This is the Dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,List<EventObj>>>> events_list; // <Year,<Month,<Day,Number of Events>>>
```

Comment: Now, why are you wanting to do this? If you're nesting these generic types this way, it's usually a clue that you're abusing them. You may be better off building some custom types to represent the actual structure, which will also make navigating it much easier, not just for you, but for future developers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer `SelectMany` for this kind of scenarios.

```
IEnumerable<EventObj> eventObjects = events_list
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value);

foreach (EventObj eventObject in eventObjects)
{
    // change the object
}
```

Or as query syntax if you are into this kind of things.. ;)

```
IEnumerable<EventObj> eventObjects =
    from years in events_list
    from months in years.Value
    from days in months.Value
    from events in days.Value
    select events;

foreach (EventObj eventObject in eventObjects)
{
    // change the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var year in events_list.Keys)
    foreach(var month in events_list[year].Keys)
         foreach(var day in events_list[year][month].Keys)
             foreach(var eventObject in events_list[year][month][day])
             {
                 // do stuff
             }
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Using a complex structure like this could become awkward and frustrating. I suggest that you create your own class that inherits from this structure, to encapsulate the logic for adding data in the structure and enumerating its entries. Here is a basic implementation:

```
public class YearMonthDayTree<T>
    : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<T>>>>
{
    public void Add(int year, int month, int day, T item)
    {
        if (!this.TryGetValue(year,
            out Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<T>>> yearDict))
        {
            yearDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<T>>>(12);
            this[year] = yearDict;
        }
        if (!yearDict.TryGetValue(month, out Dictionary<int, List<T>> monthDict))
        {
            monthDict = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>(31);
            yearDict[month] = monthDict;
        }
        if (!monthDict.TryGetValue(day, out List<T> dayList))
        {
            dayList = new List<T>();
            monthDict[day] = dayList;
        }
        dayList.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<(int Year, int Month, int Day, T Item)> Flatten()
    {
        foreach (var yearEntry in this)
        {
            int year = yearEntry.Key;
            foreach (var monthEntry in yearEntry.Value)
            {
                int month = monthEntry.Key;
                foreach (var dayEntry in monthEntry.Value)
                {
                    int day = dayEntry.Key;
                    foreach (var item in dayEntry.Value)
                    {
                        yield return (year, month, day, item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var events_list = new YearMonthDayTree<EventObj>();
events_list.Add(2019, 6, 21, new EventObj());
events_list.Add(2019, 6, 22, new EventObj());
events_list.Add(2019, 6, 22, new EventObj());
foreach (var entry in events_list.Flatten())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Year}.{entry.Month}.{entry.Day} {entry.Item}");
}
```

Output:

> 2019.6.21 EventObj
>   2019.6.22 EventObj
>   2019.6.22 EventObj